# OFDM modulator: Transmission time calculation

Tags: fft, homework, ofdm

I have a problem with a certain task.

> The frequency of the signal sampling at the OFDM modulator output is
>   20 MHz. The length of the protection period is 2 microseconds and it is
>   20% of the whole symbol, including the cyclic prefix. The size of the
>   transmitted data is 6 MB. The 16-QAM constellation is used in the
>   subchannels.

My questions are

- how to calculate the data transmission time,
- how many bits are transmitted in one OFDM symbol,
- what is the FFT size,
- what is the bandwidth of the transmitted signal and
- what will be the effective transmission speed if 25% of subchannels will be
  used for transmitting pilots.

Each data stream is divided into groups of "n" bits. Then for example QPSK constellation will have 2 bits at a time, 64-QAM constellation: 6 bits at a time and 16QAM: 4 bits at a time. And we are using 16-QAM constellation, so the answer to the second question will be 4 bits, right?

Comment: That's not one question, but five; since this is homework, please explain what you've tried and where exactly you're stuck. Can't help you understand anything without that!

Comment: @MarcusMüller okay, so I guess I found (after some research) an answer to my second question (how many bits are transmitted in one OFDM symbol) but I want to ask if it's correct. So, each data stream is divided into groups of "n" bits. Then for example QPSK constellation will have 2 bits at a time, 64-QAM constellation: 6 bits at a time and 16QAM: 4 bits at a time. And we are using 16-QAM constellation, so the answer will be **4 bits**, right?

Comment: no. you're ignoring the nature of OFDM!

Comment: @MarcusMüller so the first question should be like that: we have a sampling rate, and if 20% is 2 microseconds we must calculate 100%. So 20% - 2 microsec  100% - x. And x is 10 microseconds, and this is our data transmission time? Is it corect?

Comment: But now I dont know if I should divide my 10MHz / 10 microseconds to get number of bits in the symbol.

Comment: ok, you do understand how OFDM works in principle, right? With the subcarriers and what the cyclic prefix is?

Comment: Because the formula is (N / (2-1)) * 2 for the number of bits in each symbol. (where N is transmission path, so the size of the FFT)

Comment: the length of the FFT is not called transmission path; I think you're confusing things ; and that's a formula, but it doesn't look familiar to me in the context of OFDM at all.

Comment: So the cyclic prefix is the last sample of the symbol copied to the beginning, but it can also be a sequence of zeros or a combination of both of these versions.

Comment: no, it's neither the last sample nor a seqeunce of zeros. It's the end, typically, multiple samples, copied to the beginning of the OFDM symbol. I think you should first brush up your OFDM basics before tackling these questions!

Comment: By the way, the problem as stated can't be answered definitely – there's nothing from which one could infer the FFT length, so I guess you're missing part of the problem statement.

Comment: This is the whole task that the lecturer gave us, nothing was missing. In addition, the lecturer said that the OFDM symbol is the same as the IFFT and from this we can calculate the FFT.

Comment: Also, any information I gave here I took from our college book, maybe they are wrong but it would be strange. Btw. do you have any good websites / books from which I could learn exactly about OFDM?

Comment: yeah, well, then you're omitting some assumptions, or your lecturer forgot something.

Comment: standard book: Proakis.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I guess I should leave this task for now.

Comment: @MarcusMüller In fact, I have one more question because it's confusing for me. It is said that each symbol represents N = log2(M) bits (N is the modulation efficiency measured in bit/symbol). It's given by the Nyquist rate. Then, why I can't say that the number of bits in one OFDM symbol is 4 (if we substitute 16 for M), because we use the 16-QAM constellation in the sub channels. Why is not this true? What I am missing?

Comment: per each subcarrier, yes, you can transport 4 bit per OFDM symbol. But you've got many$=k$ used subcarriers! That means you're transporting $k\cdot \log_2{M}$ bits during one OFDM symbol. That OFDM symbol has length $l_\text{FFT}$ samples, so your data rate is $$\frac{\log_2{M} k}{\frac{l_\text{FFT}}{f_\text{sample}}}\text,$$ if we ignored the duty cycle due to cyclic prefix; we shouldn't do that, so multiply that with the percentage of OFDM payload per time.